# How to turn off document scroll when mouse scrolled - Pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, flash, mousewheel

I am having a flash interactive swf that works with mouse scroll,

I am trying to turn off the mouse scroll when the mouse is over the flash swf / the div contains the flash.

Also, the mouse scroll should work fine when the mouse is not on the flash swf / the div containing the flash.

But the mouse should work as it is working when it is on swf.

**Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/yellowandred/azfMb/**

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
       <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="1024" HEIGHT="512" id="vtour" ALIGN="">
            <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://localhost/scrollexample/abc.swf">
            <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
            <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399>
            <EMBED src="http://localhost/scrollexample/abc.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 NAME="example" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"  WIDTH="1024" HEIGHT="512" ></EMBED> 
       </OBJECT>
<div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
document.getElementByID("vtour").addEventListener('mousewheel', 
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.cancelBubble = false;
        return false;
    }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these functions

```
$("#interactive-container").bind("mousewheel", function() {
         return false;
     });
```

You can refer : [Disable mousewheel scroll on swf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445094/disable-mousewheel-scroll-on-swf-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
document.getElementByID("interactive-container").addEventListener('mousewheel', 
function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
e.cancelBubble = false;
return false;
}, false);
```

See if this helps.

Comment: I have uploaded an example on this link.. http://jsfiddle.net/yellowandred/azfMb/ help me out..